# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: php, api, youtube

i really appreciate if you can help me to find what's wrong with my code .. 
I'm trying to retrieve a data from a specific youtube channel.
The data i'm trying to retrieve is: Total View Count,Subscribers & thumbnail url.

the code show me correctly the total views and subscribers but the thumbnail code is not working.
**I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object"**

I really appreciate your time and help, thank you.

```
 <?php
function GroupViews($username) {
 $xdoc = new DomDocument;
 $xdoc->Load('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ArrolladoraLimonVEVO');
 $ytStatistics = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('statistics')->item(0);
 $totalYouTubeViews = $ytStatistics->getAttribute('totalUploadViews');
return number_format($totalYouTubeViews);
}
?>
<?php echo GroupViews(0); ?>


<?php   
    function GetytSubscribers($username) {
    $xdoc = new DomDocument;
    $xdoc->Load('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'');
    $ytStatistics = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('statistics')->item(0);
    $totalYouTubeSubscribers = $ytStatistics->getAttribute('subscriberCount');
    return number_format($totalYouTubeSubscribers);
}
?>


<?php echo GetytSubscribers('ArrolladoraLimonVEVO'); ?>





<?php   
    function GetytThumbnail($username) {
    $xdoc = new DomDocument;
    $xdoc->Load('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'');
    $ytThumbnail = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('media$thumbnail')->item(0);
    $thumbnail = $ytThumbnail->getAttribute('url');
    return number_format($thumbnail);
}
?>


<?php echo GetytThumbnail('ArrolladoraLimonVEVO'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems trickier using XML from that URL. Why wouldn't you use JSON format ? Just add '?alt=json' on your gdata.youtube url. This is example for one of your function

```
function GetytThumbnail($username) {
    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'?alt=json';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    return $obj['entry']['media$thumbnail']['url'];
}
```

You just need to change return statement for other functions. Hope it's helpful :)